# Nested <Routes> in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I decide whether to render `Foo` page or `Bar` page by route, but `Foo` page itself has two sub-routes for components to render based on the url path, like `FooOne` or `FooTwo`. So I effectively have two layers of routes: Routes > Route > Routes > Route

```
function FooTwo() {
  return <div>FooTwo</div>
}

function FooOne() {
  return <div>FooOne</div>
}

function Foo() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/foo/foo-one" element={<FooOne />} />
      <Route path="/foo/foo-two" element={<FooTwo />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

function App {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/foo/*" element={<Foo />} />
      <Route path="/bar/*" element={<Bar />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Can I do nested routes like this in React? Is it acceptable, professional practice, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do nested routes like this in React? Is it acceptable,
> professional practice, or is there a better way?

Yes, the pattern is perfectly acceptable and "professional". It's an intended use case.

***However***

What you have code are what are called ***descendent*** routes. You've an issue with the descendent route paths though. Descendent routes are built relative to the parent route, so if `Foo` is rendering descendent routes on paths `"/foo/foo-one"` and `"/foo/foo-two"` then the resulting route paths is actually `"/foo/foo/foo-one"` and `"/foo/foo/foo-two"`. `Foo` just needs to specify the sub-routes, e.g. remove the leading `"/foo"` path segment.

```
function Foo() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/foo-one" element={<FooOne />} /> // "/foo/foo-one"
      <Route path="/foo-two" element={<FooTwo />} /> // "/foo/foo-two"
    </Routes>
  );
}

function App {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/foo/*" element={<Foo />} />
      <Route path="/bar/*" element={<Bar />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

If you wanted to use ***nested*** routes, e.g. `Route` components rendered directly as children of other `Route` components, then your code could look like the following.

```
function App {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/foo">
        <Route path="foo-one" element={<FooOne />} /> // "/foo/foo-one"
        <Route path="foo-two" element={<FooTwo />} /> // "/foo/foo-two"
      </Route>
      <Route path="/bar/*" element={<Bar />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React using React Router, nesting routes, as demonstrated in your code, is a common and acceptable practice. This approach allows for the organization of routes and components in a hierarchical manner, making it suitable for handling complex layouts and multi-layered navigation. However, it's important to ensure that the nesting aligns with your application's design and user experience needs. If the nesting becomes overly complex, consider simplification or alternative approaches, but in most cases, nested routes are a practical and maintainable solution.